# React different homepage by environnement Best practices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, build

I have a different homepage in all my environment. One for staging, one for development. The issue is in each environment, I need only 1 homepage and not the other one.

Actually I have a temporary solution : with a 'if' I test and it's load the good one but I think that's not a good idea because I have to import all of my homepage when I am doing this.
All homepages are currently built when you import the files and there is some conflict with my CSS.

Maybe I need to change the webpack config, if you have some links to help me.
Or if you have some good practices to do it, that's sure be helpful !

```
import developmentHomePage from './developmentHomePage.jsx'
import stagingHomePage from './stagingHomePage.jsx'

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const currentEnvironnement = process.env.name    
  if (currentEnvironnement !== 'development') {
    homePage = developmentHomePage
  } else {
    homePage = stagingHomePage
  }

  return {
    homePage
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can fill homepage dynamically with environment variables. Check the given link to get the hint:
[dynamically fill homepage](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/998)